# startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

```
startActivityForResult(intent,3021)
```

I am using this since long time, is this method is deprecated now?

Comment: are you sure? check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: Yes, it is deprecated in new API. Read `While the underlying startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() APIs are available on the Activity class on all API levels, it is strongly recommended to use the Activity Result APIs introduced in AndroidX Activity 1.2.0-alpha02 and Fragment 1.3.0-alpha02.` Use the [`registerForActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Comment: @LalitFauzdar: "Yes, it is deprecated in new API" -- it is not deprecated [on `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)). It *is* deprecated on the AndroidX edition of `Fragment`, but the replacement (the Activity Result APIs) will not be stable for a few more months.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use deprecated method for few months @CommonsWare?

Comment: @icespirit: Yes. "Deprecated" in Android means "we have something else that we would like for you to consider". It does not mean "this code will self-destruct in 10 seconds". :-) The Activity Result APIs will be the long-term direction, but alpha code is still alpha code, and it comes with its own risks. If you want to take on those risks, you are welcome to do so.

Comment: Despite their arguments, I don't simple understand why they did this. The new APIs aren't even worth it. They left us with possibly infinite broken libraries and packages. They only look bright outside, but in reality aren't intuitive or transparent. The earlier method was very handy and simple IMHO.

Comment: yes. here is a good explanation how to use new api https://proandroiddev.com/is-onactivityresult-deprecated-in-activity-results-api-lets-deep-dive-into-it-302d5cf6edd

Comment: In which api level was it deprecated ?

Answer (score 12):

It is indeed deprecated. I tried to figure the new way out and thought I want to share it here.

Now instead of overriding `onActivityResult` for all callbacks and checking for our request code, we can register for each call back separately by using `registerForActivityResult` which takes in an `ActivityResultContracts`. IMO this is a way better approach than the previous way.

Here is an example of starting an activity for a result:

```
val previewRequest =
           registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val list = it.data
        // do whatever with the data in the callback
    }
}
```

Now instead of `StartActivityForResult` we use

```
val intent = Intent(this, PreviewFullscreenActivity::class.java)
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(AppConstants.PARAMS.IMAGE_URIS, list)
previewRequest.launch(intent)
```

Comment: What happens if we want to check for multiple requestCode? Say, location, camera, microphone etc Do we have to create multiple requests?

Comment: Xamarin android solution for deprecated api : https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2022/02/startactivityforresult-onactivityresult.html